# material ui, how to change background color, font color, border color of autocomplete textfield

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

How can I change the background color, font color, and border color of this material-ui autocomplete textfield (combobox)?  I would like to use css.  this is what I have tried so far.

```
    <Autocomplete
      disablePortal
      id="combo-box-demo"
      options={clients}
      className="test"
      renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Movie" />}
    />
```

css class

```
.test {
  .MuiAutocomplete-listbox {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you would like to use css, you can change colors like this:

```
.test fieldset {
  border-color: red;
}

.test .MuiInputBase-root:hover fieldset {
  border-color: blue;
}

.test input {
  color: red;
}

.test label {
  color: red;
}

.test {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

You can take a look at [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-autocomplete-css-cr6n3k?file=/mycss.css) for a live working example.

Comment: so this worked thank you!  can you tell me how I could have figured that out?  this is new to me and I'm trying to understand documentation and things like that

Comment: You are welcome. In material-ui, there are many ways to handle component styles [global-style-overrides](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theme-components/#global-style-overrides) is an alternative. However, if you would like to use css, you need to inspect elements on developer tools of the browser and find out css classes of the elements and then add a more specified css to override current styles. That's my way to do it.

Comment: i'm really trying to understand this properly.  using the inspector if I highlight the area in question, I get the 1st picture I attached.  if I type things on the right side of inspector as in 2nd picture it changes things.  Is this the proper way?  how do I put that in the css file, ie. height: 400px for example

Comment: You need to write a more specified css like `.test .MuiInputBase-root : {height: 400px}` so that you will be able to override any default styles related to `.MuiInputBase-root` class. You can also use `!important` keyword to make your css more prioritized like `.test .MuiInputBase-root : {height: 400px !important}`.

Comment: sorry to keep at this but I'm trying to find more specifics.  take a look at last pic I attached. "movie" is not centered, nor the selections.  I tried  .test .MuiOutlinedInput-root {
      height: 30px;
      background-color: #eeeeee;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
    }  but nothing working.  do you see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Could you reproduce it in a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) or [https://stackblitz.com/](https://stackblitz.com/)?